# output[0] = y0 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: numpy, scipy, gaussian, normal-distribution, numerical-integration

I have been struggling for a few days with this. I'm trying t estimate the density of a piecewise gaussian function. Could anyone tell me why I'm now getting the error

```
TypeError:     output[0] = y0
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

It happens on this line:

```
Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(gaussian(q,x,mu,sigma), Q1, Q2).`
```

Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from scipy import integrate
from sympy import Integral, log, exp, sqrt, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde
from quantecon import LAE

from sympy import symbols
var('Q1 Q2 x q sigma mu')
#q= symbols('q')

## == Define parameters == #
mu=80
sigma=20
b=0.2
Q=80
Q1=Q*(1-b)
Q2=Q*(1+b)
d = (sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
phi = norm()
n = 500

def p(x, y):
    x, y = np.array(x, dtype=float), np.array(y, dtype=float)
    Positive_RG = norm.pdf(x-y+Q1, mu, sigma)
    print('Positive_R = ', Positive_RG)
    Negative_RG = norm.pdf(x-y+Q2, mu, sigma) 
    print('Negative_RG = ', Negative_RG)
    gaussian = lambda q,x,mu,sigma: 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x+q-mu)**2 /(2*sigma**2))
    wrapped_gaussian = lambda q: gaussian(q, x, mu, sigma)
    Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(wrapped_gaussian, Q1, Q2)
    print('pdf',gaussian)
    #Zero_RG = scipy.integrate.quad(norm.pdf(x + q, mu, sigma))
#    Int_zerocase= lambda q: norm.pdf(x + q, u, sigma)
#    Zero_RG = scipy.integrate.quad(Int_zerocase, Q1, Q2)
#    print(Zero_RG)

    if y>0.0 and x -y>=-Q1:
        #print('printA', Positive_RG)
        return Positive_RG
    elif y<0.0 and x -y>=-Q2:
        #print('printC', Negative_RG)
        return Negative_RG
    elif y==0.0 and x >=-Q1:
        #print('printB', Zero_RG)
        return Zero_RG
    return 0.0 


Z = phi.rvs(n)
X = np.empty(n)
for t in range(n-1):
    X[t+1] = X[t] + Z[t]
    #X[t+1] = np.abs(X[t]) + Z[t]
psi_est = LAE(p, X)
k_est = gaussian_kde(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ys = np.linspace(-200.0, 200.0, 200)
ax.plot(ys, psi_est(ys), 'g-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='look ahead estimate')
ax.plot(ys, k_est(ys), 'k-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='kernel based estimate')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The first argument to the `integeate.romberg` function must be a function.  You give it `gausian(...)`, the result of calling a lambda with arguments.

Comment: @hpaulj, Still not working. I have waisted 2 days trying this :-) ....

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`romberg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romberg.html) are pretty clear that the first argument is a function of a single variable that gets integrated.

First, a minor point. Use `np.exp` in preference to `np.e**`.

In Python, the expression

```
gaussian = lambda q,x,mu,sigma: 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x+q-mu)**2 /(2*sigma**2))
```

sets `gaussian` to a function of four arguments. The expression `gaussian(q, x, mu, sigma)` is just the return value of that function.

There are two ways to pass in the required parameters to the `romberg`. The easiest way is to use the `args` parameter to pass in the three additional arguments as a tuple:

```
Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(gaussian, Q1, Q2, args=(x,mu,sigma))
```

The other way is to create a wrapper function that will pass the arguments for you:

```
wrapped_gaussian = lambda q: gaussian(q, x, mu, sigma)
Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(wrapped_gaussian, Q1, Q2)
```

I would recommend the fist approach because it uses an existing mechanism, as well as being shorter and easier to read.

Comment: both ways work but creating another error. which states in the second case for instance: Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(wrapped_gaussian, Q1, Q2),  output[0] = y0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What about the first case?

Comment: Also, change `np.e**(...)` to `np.exp(...)`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question with a full stack trace. Better yet, ask a new question.

Comment: Many thanks, I'm doing so now. Also trying what you have suggested and see what happens.

Comment: Many Thanks @Mad Physicist. I was just trying to implement what you said, hence the delay in upvoting. But It is not really working as it says now that: in line  `Zero_RG = integrate.romberg(wrapped_gaussian, Q1, Q2)` output[0] = y0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @EricEnkele. I go that part, although I still need to see the full formatted stack trace to really know what is going on. Please ask another question and include that information.